# Using flags to remove repeated items in a table

Tags: velocity

I am currently working on an email project using Apache Velocity. In the email, I have a table where each row is a persons name followed by a value.  Each person can have multiple rows, but the name should only display the first time it appears in the table. I am currently using flags to toggle whether the name has been shown or not. My question is if there is a better way to accomplish this than by using flags. Here is my current code, a bit watered down:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    #foreach( $person in $view.people )
        #set($nameDisplayed = false)
        #foreach($personInfo in $person.infos)
            #if($personInfo.value1 > 0)
                <tr>
                    <td>#if(!$nameDisplayed) $person.name #end </td>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr>
                #set($nameDisplayed = true)
            #end
        #end

        #if($person.value2 > 0)
            <tr>
                <td>#if(!$nameDisplayed) $person.name #end </td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            #set($nameDisplayed = true)
        #end 

        #if($person.value3 > 0)
             <tr>
                <td>#if(!$nameDisplayed) $person.name  #end </td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            #set($nameDisplayed = true)
        #end 
    #end
</table>
```

Here is a sample of possible outcomes:

```
Name  Value
Rick    1
        2
Morty   1
        1
        3
Filipe  2
        3
Jose    3
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I think `$velocityCount` will do the trick. Like:

```
#foreach( $person in $view.people )
    #foreach($personInfo in $person.infos)
        <tr>
            <td>
                #if($velocityCount == 1)
                    $person.name
                #end
            </td>
            <td>[value]</td
        </td>
    #end
#end
```

This example most probably won't work as I can't test it and some fiddling has to be done, but it should illustrate the idea alright.

Every for-each-loop has its own `$velocityCount`. So if necessary you can place another one in the outer loop and do some calculation (I'm saying that, because I couldn't figure out how the values are made and you don't read'em from an object).

Comment: $velocityCount could work, but I feel that since I have an inner #foreach loop, the calculation required to get it to work would make it more complicated than using the flags.